# Rename Computer (WMI-Powershell ) to previous used name

Tags: powershell, wmi

Looking for a way, in PowerShell & WMI, to rename a computer with a name that was previous used. Also,this same procedure is successful when performing through Windows Properties.

```
$computerSystem = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem

#### Rename-Host                          ####
Function Rename-Host {
    Param($computerSystem,
          $newComputerName,
          $username = $null,
          $password = $null)

    Write-Host "RenameHost: Attempting to change from $($computerSystem.DNSHostName) to $newComputerName"
    Write-Host "RenameHost: Pinging for Host-Name $newComputerName to ensure it does not already exist."
    $pingReturn = Ping-Addresses $newComputerName
    if($pingReturn.Reachable -eq 'true'){
        Write-StdErr "RenameComputer: Failed $newComputerName already exists on Network."
        return
    }
    $oldComputerName = $computerSystem.DNSHostName
    $renameResult = $computerSystem.Rename($newComputerName,$password,$username).ReturnValue
    switch($renameResult){
        0 { Write-Host "RenameHost: Successfully renamed $oldComputerName to $newComputerName" }
        default { Write-StdErr "RenameHost: Failed with Error = $renameResult" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason the Rename-Computer command would not suffice? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849792.aspx

Comment: I am investigating if DHCP server is holding on to the hostname.

Comment: DHCP should hold onto leases until it reaches the timeout period. When doing mass renames or if we were running out of IPs, we have dropped the lease times to 5 minutes to ensure IP's were released for use as soon as possible. But even if DHCP has a lease, this shouldn't prevent a rename as long as the new name isn't part of the domain.